How to prevent automatically rebuild open pull request when target branch is updated (when another Pull Request is merged)
I have a GitHub repo with many developers, hence many pull requests are opened at the same time.
This repo has a webhook - a Jenkins multibranch pipeline.
When a pull request is merged, all other opened pull requests are triggered in Jenkins and run again.
Normally, this is the desired behavior, but since this repo has many pull request that are opened simultaneously, it causes a lot a load on the Jenkins server - sometimes 20 builds are triggered and run at the same time.
How can I prevent open pull requests from automatically rebuilding after merge to the target branch?

Would throttling concurrent builds accomplish what you need? https://plugins.jenkins.io/throttle-concurrents/ Or are you looking for a way to skip these builds altogether?

The basic-branch-build-strategies plugin does exactly that.

